# Execute Javascript when user scrolls past certain distance from top

Tags: javascript, html, menu, scroll

Basically what I'm trying to do is to keep on top and resize the horizontal menu on my website after it starts to hide (after the user has scrolled more than 210px from the top of the document). But I don't know how to apply the styles after 210px. And this I am trying to do with pure Javascript. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get scroll position **(crossbrowser script)**

```
function getScrollXY(callback) {
    var scrOfX = 0, scrOfY = 0;

    if( typeof( window.pageYOffset ) == 'number' ) {
        //Netscape compliant
        scrOfY = window.pageYOffset;
        scrOfX = window.pageXOffset;
    } else if( document.body && ( document.body.scrollLeft || document.body.scrollTop ) ) {
        //DOM compliant
        scrOfY = document.body.scrollTop;
        scrOfX = document.body.scrollLeft;
    } else if( document.documentElement && ( document.documentElement.scrollLeft || document.documentElement.scrollTop ) ) {
        //IE6 standards compliant mode
        scrOfY = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        scrOfX = document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
    }


    //return [ scrOfX, scrOfY ];

    if( scrOfY >= arguments[1] )
        callback();
}
```

calling the function like

```
getScrollXY(myFunctionThatShouldBeCalled, 210);
```

instead of return you could check if the scrolled position (scrOfY) is > 210 and than call a function or like i changed it a callback function if you may have diffrent functions to call.

The callback part is untested. But it should work.

**EDIT:**

After a little watching of this code there might could be a short form of writing that. I havent tested it so far but i'll just provide you with this one.

```
var doE = document.documentElement;
var scrolledX = window.pageXOffset || self.pageXOffset || (doE&&doE.scrollLeft) || document.body.scrollLeft;
var scrolledY = window.pageYOffset || self.pageYOffset || (doE&&doE.scrollTop)  || document.body.scrollTop;

if( scrolledY >= 210)
    /** do some here **/
```

Comment: Come on! If you're pasting code from the 90s (Netscape…), at least give credit http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/browserwindow. And instead of fumbling around with short forms, take this battle-tested version: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.scrollY#Notes

Comment: @Pumbaa80 fine for you that you found it there... but i never visited this side. my browser displays german pages so if i give credits to a page where may 10 % can read it makes no sence. And the short form is written by my self so no need to flame around here. Nice for you if you found some similar. AND, if you read my post right, you will see that i never sayed its my code... have a look at: `After a little watching of this code...` I say THIS CODE and not MY code.

Answer (score 2):

I think the example you may be looking for is here.

This shows an example of an up arrow after 500px of scroll.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onscroll Example #3.

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
if(window.pageYOffset>210){
    //restyle
}
```

`window.pageYOffset` is the amount you have scrolled down the page.

Edit:  You can combine this with Dwza's answer to get a cross-browser version.  Instead of `window.pageYOffset`, use `getScrollXY()[1]`